# uploadify send button id

Tags: php, uploadify

I would like to have multiple uploadify buttons and be able to tell what file input was clicked.  Is there a way to get the id of the button that was clicked or some other way to identify the file?
For example I would like to know that the first input with ID "job_1237_1" was clicked if I have inputs:

```
    <input class="file_selector" type="file" name="file_upload" id="job_1237_1" /><br />
    <input class="file_selector" type="file" name="file_upload" id="job_1237_2" />
```

with JS:

```
$('.file_selector').uploadify({
// options...
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with uploadify, but does it force you to name all your file elements "file_upload"? If not, give them different names, and the name of the one that was used will show up in the receiving page's $_POST array.

Comment: More precisely, all of them will show up, but only the one that was used will have a filename associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
'onUploadStart' : function(){
$('#file_selector').uploadifySettings(
    'postData', 
    {
        "name": $("#job_1237_1").val(),
        "userId": $("#job_1237_2").val()
    }
);
},
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful here.

Comment: The ID's are variable so hard-coding them in will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the "auto" option set to false. When I click the submit form button I loop through the file inputs
HTML:

```
<input class="file_selector" type="file" name="file_upload" id="job_1237_1" /><br />
<input class="file_selector" type="file" name="file_upload" id="job_1237_2" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(".file_selector").each(function () {
    var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).uploadify('settings', 'formData', {input_id: inputId});
    $(this).uploadify('upload');
});
```

This will send the id with the file to the posting page.